# Navigation View issue in android studio

Tags: navigation-drawer, android-drawable, navigationbar, navigationview, android-navigationview

I try using navigation view but it didn't work. 
I also clean the project and build it again and then, I invalidate the project but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow please follow [this guideline] before asking a question thank you

Comment: What guideline?

Comment: sorry [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

maybe its bugs you can try add **tools:openDrawer="start"** in your main view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_default"/>
        <fragment
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
            />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
            />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```